# Angular ui-router abstract state $scope not erased

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a hybrid application with ionic.
I have the side menu layout with ui-router configured as follows-

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      cache: false,
      controller: 'LoginCtrl',
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      resolve: {
        requireNoAuth: function($state, Auth){
          return Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(auth){
            $state.go('menu.search');
          }, function(error){
            return;
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .state('menu', {
      url: '/menu',
      abstract:true,
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
      resolve: {
        auth: function($state, Auth){
          return Auth.$requireAuth().catch(function(){
            $state.go('login'); //if not authenticated send back to login
          });
        },
        profile: function(Users, Auth){
          return Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(auth){
            return Users.getProfile(auth.uid).$loaded(); //get profile for user.
          }).catch(function(){
            console.log("Auth failed");
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .state('menu.search', {
      url: '/search',
      views: {
        'menu': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
          controller: 'SearchCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
```

Here is my AppCtrl

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, auth, profile, AuthService, $state){
  $scope.user = profile;
  $scope.logout = function(){
    AuthService.logoutUser().then(function(){
      $state.go('login');
    });
  }
});
```

LogoutService -

```
logoutUser: function () {
            var d = $q.defer();
            self.current = {};
            Auth.$unauth();
            d.resolve();
            return d.promise;
        }
```

And the logout button -

```
<ion-item ng-click = "logout()" menu-close="">Logout</ion-item>
```

The side menu requires 'profile' object so I can display information in side menu. The problem is that it seems abstract state controller gets instantiated only the first time user logs in. Here is a scenario

```
User 1 logs in - 
  User 1 profile loaded in side menu and properly displayed
  User 1 logout
Now without closing the window/ app
User 2 logs in -
   User 2 profile gets loaded in all child states but the side menu $scope.user still contains user 1 information.
```

Does this mean the parent controller dependency gets resolved only once? How do make sure the AppCtrl resolves the profile correctly every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself -
I suspected that the side menu was 'remembering' the scope variable. So i set `cache: false` in `.menu` state configuration and it no longer remembers the previous users information.